# What are the advantages of using std::variant as opposed to traditional polymorphic processing?

Tags: c++, variant, boost-variant

Suppose I have a `Shape` base class and `Circle`, `Line`, and `Point` derived classes. I have two functions.

```
std::variant<Circle, Line, Point> process(const Shape &s);
Shape process(const Shape& s);
```

I can pass in any of my derived classes and return a Shape object in the second function, a variant is just a union that can hold any of my derived class variables at any given time.

Now with `std::variant` I can also employ a `visitor` where I can process some function depending on what type my variant is currently holding (I could just create a function object and pass it `std::transform` and apply it to each of my objects). However, I can just make that function `virtual` in my base class and have each derived class implement it.

So, is `variant` just a convenience?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that `std::variant`'s template arguments must share a common base. You can store unrelated types in an `std::variant`.

Comment: imho too broad, though the most obvious is that you can put any types into a variant, while you cannot use a `Circle` and a `Rectangle` polymorphically, unless they both inherit `Shape`, thats a small but big difference

Comment: eg `std::variant<int,double,std::string>`, no chance to get anywhere close to that via inheritance

Comment: FWIW: `Shape process(const Shape& s)` isn't the same as `std::variant<Circle, Line, Point> process(const Shape &s)` as the former [slices the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).  You need to return by reference/smart pointer/pointer.

Comment: @user463035818 "no chance": You could define wrapper classes around with common base class. Close to? I'd say so - maybe.... Ugly? Sure...

Comment: @Aconcagua But then you wouldn't have a `std::variant<int,double,std::string>` anymore.

Comment: Nice comparison is here: [Inheritance vs `std::variant`](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2018/02/inheritance-vs-stdvariant-based.html)

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah i was expecting someone to disagree. Replace "no chance to get anywhere close to" as "it would be so tedious and not nice that you wouldnt usually consider it as an option" and I guess we can agree ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Sure... Hm, and I must admit I did not consider aesthetics being a potential measure for distance - with that one, it would get quite large...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So, is variant just a convenience?

No, they are different concepts. Main difference that on one side `std::variant` can work with unrelated types including builtins like `int` which is not possible with virtual functions directly. On another side `std::variant` must know types it is working with at compile time. For example it is possible to add a type with virtual function(s) by just linking additional object module without recompiling rest of the code or loading a shared library dynamically to existing application (you do not even have to restart the app) while with `std::variant` you must recompile code dealing with types `std::variant` contains.

Answer (score 4):

> However, I can just make that function virtual in my base class and have each derived class implement it.

Yes.... if all the elements in the `variant` share a common Base (which [Slava already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297152/27678)).

Another big difference is that, with a `variant`, there's not necessarily *any* dynamic polymorphism happening at all (no RTTI needed) during visitation.

In conjunction with `std::visit`, there are a lot of tricks under the hood to make sure that there's (basically) zero runtime overhead in calling the appropriate function for a given `std::variant`. Although there could be non-trivial additional compile time and memory usage because it does this by creating a big matrix of function pointers ([See this excellent blog post from Michael Park](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2015/07/07/variant-visitation/) about it)